# Meaning of Deterioration

Tags: meaning

For example:

"If mullahs are deteriorated in the Islamic schools, bring them to the tavern to correct their ways"

If someone is deteriorated, does it mean they ruin their good behaviors and become bad by going to a bad place along with some evil people, i.e,  visiting Tavern, Bar, Strumpet, etc..

Comment: Transitive *deteriorate* (defined by OED as *to make worse or of inferior quality*) is fairly unusual, and doesn't make much sense in your cited context anyway. It looks like either a bad translation or something written by a non-native speaker. But since when would any mullahs ("deteriorated" or otherwise) be likely to go to a ***tavern*** (olde-worlde drinking establishment) for enlightenment? It's a somewhat nonsensical context all ways round.

Comment: Ok mister mind, it's from an English news paper of India

Comment: I find it hard to believe ***tavern*** has been retained as a "natural" colloquial usage in Indian English, so I don't think the writer there is meaningfully reflecting a style of English that's worth learning or emulating. It's just incompetent writing from someone who doesn't know English very well, I would say. (I'm afraid your ***strumpet*** is a bit "Shakespearean", too! :)

Comment: It seems like a  translation of some urdu couplet. Is it so?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I go to the Bar and Strumpet all the time. Over on the high street across from the green. It's not a bad place. They draw a nice pint and quiz nights are fun.

Comment: @deadrat: There's *The Tavern on the Green* down the road from me. But it's a deliberately "twee" usage, like *The Frog and Nightgown* (also not that far away, an old watering-hole of mine back when I could afford pints in pubs and taxis to get home! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking us to explain poorly translated poetry whose result is not correct English.

Answer (score 1):

Better to say,

> Since the quality of the mullahs has deteriorated lately, I recommend sending them back to madrasa for a refresher course.

The place for bad mullahs to go is not to a tavern but to a school where they can receive instruction on how to become better mullahs. In the Arabic language, a *madrasa* (loosely, school) would be just such a place for them to go.

As for the word *deteriorated*: describing a person as *deteriorated* could be correct in some situations. For example, in speaking of someone with a worsening disease you might say,

> His condition has deteriorated over the past few months.

Or simply,

> He deteriorated over the past few months.

(In the above sentence, the implication is that someone's health or some specified condition has gotten worse. The condition could be physical, mental, spiritual, or possibly a combination of all three.)

Generally speaking, however, it is some ***thing***, not some *one*, which deteriorates. Some examples:

> - Test scores have deteriorated steadily over the past five years.
> - His health deteriorated to the point where he needed hospice care.
> - The condition of the house quite naturally deteriorated over time, since no one cared enough to fix it up and maintain it.
> - Diplomatic relations between the two countries deteriorated once the threat of war became a distinct possibility.

Comment: The example is from a hater of Mullahs

Comment: A Hindu man who want to insult Mullahs becuse they dont like taverns that's why hindus say bring them to tavern

Comment: @Arman: OK, I think I understand the humor now. Muslims, in general, eschew the drinking of alcohol, so naturally, going to a tavern--a place where alcohol is served--would be against their religion and offensive to them.

Comment: It's not a very *good* line of attack for a humorous barb. Even though it's not idiomatic, specifically saying the mullahs have "deteriorated" implies that properly-schooled mullahs would be desirable. But the idea of mullahs learning from drunks doesn't make a lot of sense - it's like saying if Donald Trump doesn't know how to treat women he should be sent to a brothel where he can learn how to show them more respect.